# Given $A \in SL_n(\Bbb R)$ Find $B,P \in SL_n(\Bbb R)$ such that, $A=BPB^{-1}P^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-groups

> I was trying to prove that, $[SL_n(\Bbb R), SL_n(\Bbb R)]=SL_n(\Bbb R)$

My attempt:

$[SL_n(\Bbb R), SL_n(\Bbb R)]\subset SL_n(\Bbb R)$ is trivial, trying to prove the other inclusion.

> So it's enough to show that given any $A \in SL_n(\Bbb R)$ $\exists B,P \in SL_n(\Bbb R)$ such that,  $A=BPB^{-1}P^{-1}$ .

In fact, I proved that $SL_n(\Bbb R)$ is generated by elementary matrices of the form $\{I_n+\lambda e_{ij} | \lambda\in \Bbb R , i \ne j\}$.

So the problem can be reduced to :

> Given an elementary matrix of the above form say, $E=I_n+\lambda e_{ij}$ find , $B,P \in SL_n(\Bbb R)$ such that $E=BPB^{-1}P^{-1}$

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Hint: Can you show that the only normal subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ are $\left\{ \operatorname{Id} \right\}, \left\{ \pm \operatorname{Id} \right\}$ (when $n$ is even), and $\operatorname{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ itself? Then since $\left[ \operatorname{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{R}), \operatorname{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \right]$ is a normal subgroup, all you need rule out is that it is not $\left\{ \pm \operatorname{Id} \right\}  $ when $n$ is even.

Comment: "So it's enough to show that given any $A \in SL_n(\Bbb R)$ $\exists B,P \in SL_n(\Bbb R)$ such that,  $A=BPB^{-1}P^{-1}$ ." Yes, that's enough to show. But I'm far from sure that it is correct. Being a product of commutators is a weaker property than being a commutator oneself.